# Point with zero electric potential inside triangle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential

> If we have three equal point charges placed on a two dimensional plane at $(a_x, a_y)$, $(b_x, b_y)$ and $(c_x, c_y)$, what would then be the coordinates of the point at which the electric potential is zero?

It seem that this point always exists and that it is somewhere inside the triangle formed by these points.

I tried to decompose the field in its components, but from that I couldn't get to a solution.

Comment: Why are you not working directly with the potential (which you do not need to decompose into components).

Comment: Agreed; no need to calculate the electric field vectors, just work out the form of the total (scalar) potential field.

Comment: Furthermore, there should be not point with potential zero, if your reference is infinity. I guess you mean vanishing electrical field. But even then it is much simpler to calculate the potential and find its local extrema.

Answer (score 1):

I will presume that, as is standard and conventional, the electric potential at a place an infinite distance from the one in consideration is zero. Let the charge at point a be charge $a$, the charge at point b be charge $b$ and the charge at point c be charge $c$. With this, the formula for the electric potential is:

> $V = \frac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}(\frac{1}{distance-from-a} + \frac{1}{distance-from-b} + \frac{1}{distance-from-c})$

Here, I have not written out the distance formulas, only using words, because they are not necessary. From this formula, since distances are always positive and the charges are always of the same sign, the electric potential will never be zero.

As for the electric field, if that is what you meant, do as Sebastian said and find the local extrema of the potential function. Its from here a bunch of maths.